# Alternatives to VS2010 Test Professional/Team Server?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, testing

I am looking for an alternative to Test Professional/Team Server that hopefully is free.

They can be multiple tools/ hosted tools(hosted might be better).

What I am looking to do is

1. Load Testing.
2. Performance Test( So I need something that can simulate like users on the site so I can see how my site handles with 50 users, then 500 users and so forth).
3. Manual Testing log.

So VS 2010 Test professional has

> Embrace manual testing
>
> Visual Studio Test Professional 2010
>   provides a modern interface for manual
>   testing that walks you through test
>   steps while collecting important
>   information to include in bugs—items
>   like Diagnostic Trace, Event Log,
>   Action Log, Network Emulation, and
>   System Information—that can be filed
>   directly from the test interface.

I not sure if anything else on the market has something like that but if it would allow you to like write a test plan then every time you are about to manually test it you can make a copy of it.

So maybe on May 15th you create a test plan and test it and conclude all tests passed.

Then on June 1st you want to do the entire test plan again to see if you did not break anything. You would just like go to your previous test plan on May 15th and copy it then go through all the tests.

This way you have a log of all the times you tested those items in your test plan and can compare to see how passed each time.

I am using

Asp.net MVC 2.0,
.NET 4.0,
Linq to sql + ado.net, C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into BizSpark or WebSpark if you're a startup, or might be considered one.  They give you free everything, pretty much, for as long as three years.

Comment: Hmm that sounds cool. Do they have VS2010(Ultimate,Pro,Premium)? Also one concern I had with team edition is that  I need a server. Not sure how long that would take. Also how many licenses do you get for each thing?

Comment: I have Ultimate through them.  The enrollment materials specify all that.  I can't remember the specifics on TFS or other titles, but I pretty much guarantee that it's plenty.  If you need TFS, I'm pretty sure you can get a hosted version (or possibly virtualize?  But if you don't have more than one machine, why TFS?).  But TFS as a build server, I'm pretty sure, won't help you with load-testing.  Just unit-testing, really.  TFS is hard to get set up properly.  Spend time writing your software, not preparing to write it.

Comment: Me and another person are working on it. So we have 2 machines but we develop on them. I looked at the site and the software but it must be old as it only listed 2008 stuff so I wanted to make sure(So if got a updated link that would be area).  It probably won't help me with load testing but the other person working with me thought it might be good for performance testing(with current users and stuff). So we wanted to install it and try it out.

Comment: No, I don't think it would help with performance testing.  I just looked and I see Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Foundation Server Standard Edition (x86) is available for download.  Joining BizSpark is free and pretty easy to maintain, so I recommend it either way.

Comment: **Virtualize**  Like VMWare ESXi - free, easy.  ESXi needs its own box but ROCKS absolutely.  What general geographical area are you in?

Comment: I am in Canada. I think the performance stuff is now in ultimate now. I still like this Test professional program but I don't want to spend more then a day or 2 of getting it setup(as long as it has the basic stuff up I will be happy. I don't need the super fancy graphs).

Comment: Does it really need it's own server this ESXi. In reality for the time being it will have to be on a computer that I am using at the same time for development.

Comment: Yes, ESXi is a low-overhead OS that runs on the hardware directly.  But it will run on pretty much ANYTHING, so just find a shitty old box from a sysadmin friend or something and put it on there.  You'll be so pleased.  There are both Microsoft and VMWare solution that work on top of your existing Windows installation, but IMHO they are more trouble than they're worth, especially for a TFS server that should be always on...

Comment: You could also install Windows Server 2008 on your laptop as your primary OS.  That's what I've done - works GREAT.  All the comforts of home, with a little work (except bluetooth, for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

A few tips on tools..

C# Code coverage:
http://ncover.sourceforge.net/

Performance testing:
http://jmeter.apache.org/

Link checker:
http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/

Bug management:
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/

Test Script/Planning mgmt:
http://www.teamst.org/